# How do you use more emoticons in Office Communicator?

Tags: fonts, instant-messaging, office-communicator-2007, symbols, emoticons

Is there any way to use emoticons beyond the default drop down list in Office Communicator 2007 R2? Do you have to install them, or can you just type in different codes? Is this even possible, or are the defaults the only ones you can use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't, according to [the MSDN forums](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/commmunicatorim/thread/1c4cc1c1-bf4b-4edb-acb0-2028dd0586be) (and their user Thom Foreman):

> There is no way to add emoticons to
>   OC. I have not heard of plans on
>   adding them to future releases. I will
>   put this as a feature request.

Comment: sad face :-(​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 7):

Change your font to [Wingdings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings). Use the Windows [Character Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map) (in menu *Start* / *Programs* / *Accessories* / *System Tools* on some versions of Windows) to pick the picture you want to use. That's the only way. It's also a fun thing to do as others will ask you where you got them from.

Answer (score 5):

Just [type them in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons) ^^ (sorry!)

Answer (score 3):

Since Office Communicator is a business application, there is no add-ons available for it apart from the official Communicator Server add-ons. As far as I am aware there is no additional emoticons for Communicator.