# Can you have more than 10 people in office communicator chat room?

Tags: ms-office-communicator

It seems like office communicator has a 10 person max on it.  Do you know that is?  Is there anyway to get more names in a single shared chat room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office communicator is something I use at work. I have dug through every setting I can find and I do not see any options anywhere to modify this limit.  Maybe it is hardset and you cannot change it?

I asked a question once about extra emoticons in office communicator and there was no way to expand them as the built in ones were the only options.
[How do you use more emoticons in Office Communicator?](https://superuser.com/questions/10343/how-do-you-use-more-emoticons-in-office-communicator)